# How to start rsyslog from supervisor in docekr container?

Tags: docker, rsyslog

I want to start `rsyslog` as an additional process in a docker container, because my main service requires it for logging. Therefore trying to set it up with `supervisor`. But the following fails with a restart-loop for rsyslog. Why?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN set -e \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes \
        rsyslog \
        supervisor

COPY /services/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/console.conf
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.conf"]
```

supervisor.conf:

```
[supervisord]
#start in foreground
nodaemon=true

[program:syslog]
command=service rsyslog start

#[programm:another]
#command=...
```

Result:

```
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:09,906 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:09,907 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:10,910 INFO spawned: 'syslog' with pid 9
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:10,987 INFO exited: syslog (exit status 0; not expected)
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:11,990 INFO spawned: 'syslog' with pid 22
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:11,999 INFO exited: syslog (exit status 0; not expected)
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:14,003 INFO spawned: 'syslog' with pid 28
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:14,014 INFO exited: syslog (exit status 0; not expected)
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:17,020 INFO spawned: 'syslog' with pid 34
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:17,030 INFO exited: syslog (exit status 0; not expected)
process    | 2022-10-27 10:07:17,031 INFO gave up: syslog entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't set `command=service ...`, since the `service` command (if it works at all) will start the service in the background and exit immediately.  Run the syslog daemon as a foreground process instead, without wrapping it in another layer of init script.

Comment: (Do you _need_ this setup?  Can you reconfigure your application to log to stdout?  Or can you set the syslog destination to another container or to the host, or bind-mount a Unix socket into the container?)

Comment: The service I'm trying to dockerize is not in my control. So no, I cannot change the logging inside. I'd prefer having a single container without dependencies to other containers, neither to the host system.

Comment: I recommend you post your question on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), as (i would guess) the number of experts on rsyslog/docker is higher over there.